# Java writing in the node.exe console window

Tags: java, node.js, console

I need help writing to the [`Node.exe` console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DByuU.png) in Java.

I am currently using a `ProcessBuilder` to open up the process then I need to write in the console with a separate step.

Step 1 looks like this which works fine:

```
ProcessBuilder b = new ProcessBuilder("node.exe","/c");
b.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = builder.start();
p.waitFor();
```

Step 2 which is where I need help:

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"node.exe" + "some text"});
```

One issue is that many items of node can be running at one time and I use a command line piece of code to get that PID with the first step.

But all I need to do is write text in that command window above, which will be the last process of node that was made.

How I can write a simple line of text in that command window in the screen shot?

I added this but it still does not work

```
OutputStream stdin = process.getOutputStream();
InputStream stderr = process.getErrorStream();
InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(stdin);
writer.write("test");
writer.flush();
stdin.close();
System.out.print(reader.read());
```

Comment: Don't `waitFor` node to finish. Write something into the `OutputStream`  that connects you to that window.

Comment: Thats where I am stuck, I need to connect to that window but dont know how can you provide an example?

Comment: Also I need the waitFor; as the process that opens the window flashes 3 times